# MongoDBObject not being added to inside of an rrd foreach loop casbah scala apache spark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, casbah

Ok guru's, i've got a problem that doesnt make much sense to me.
I am stuck trying to save an object to mongodb that looks like such (roughly)

```
{data:[baseball:[{timestamp (essentially):tweet},{timestamp: another tweet}]
       football:[{timestamp:footballtweet},{timestamp:differentfootballtweet}]
      ]
 timeInterval:"last minute to this minute" ( i'm doing timeseries data)
 terms:["football","baseball"]
}
```

see below on which loop im stuck on. note the issue might have something to do with the 
rrd expiring. I tried to fix it by persisting it in memory but i'm not sure what to do.

```
   twitterStream.foreachRDD(rrd => {
          val entryToSave = MongoDBObject()
          val termWithTweets = MongoDBObject()
          rrd.persist()
          filters.foreach(term =>{
          var listOfTweets = MongoDBObject()
            rrd.persist()
            for(status <- rrd){
              if(status.getText.contains(term)) {
    //            listOfTweets += status
//Why doesnt this line below actually add the key value pair to the variable
//defined outside of the "for(status <- rrd)" loop? I know ( through debugging)
//that it does in fact append inside the loop.

                listOfTweets += (DateTime.now.toString() -> status.toString)
              }
            }
//when I print the listOfTweets outside of the for loop it is empty, Why?
            println("outsideRRD",listOfTweets)
              termWithTweets += (term -> listOfTweets)
          })
          entryToSave += ("data" -> termWithTweets)
          entryToSave += ("timeInterval" -> (DateTime.lastMinute to DateTime.now).toString)
          entryToSave += ("terms" -> filters)
          collection.insert(entryToSave)
        })
```

I dont think this is a val/var issue, although it may be. I've tried it
both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computations on RDD's are distributed over the cluster. You can't update a variable that was created outside the RDD operation closure from within the RDD. They are basically in two different places: The variable is created in the Spark driver and accessed in the workers and should be treated as read-only.

Spark supports distributed cummulators that could be used in this case:
[Spark Cummulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators)

Another option (the one I'd prefer) is to transform the stream of RDD into the desired data format and the use the `foreachRDD` method to persist it into secondary storage. This would be a more functional way to approach the problem. It would roughly look like this:

```
  val filteredStream = twitterStream.filter(entry => filters.exists(term => entry.getText.getStatus.contains(term)))
  val filteredStreamWithTs = filteredStream.map(x => ((DateTime.now.toString(), x)))
  filteredStreamWithTs.foreachRdd(rdd => // write to Mongo)
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. This would indeed be the more functional way to do it. I did not realize that was the way an operation with an RRD would have to happen.